# Oracle 10g Datamasking

Tags: database, oracle10g

I have Oracle 10g database. I want to mask my record of tables. It doesn't really need to make sense, it doesn't need to be readable. Just needs to be masked. For example:

```
select *
from customer;

LAST_NAME      FIRST_NAME     ADDRESS
-------------- -------------- --------------------
Doe            John           10 someroad st
```

i convert to this :

```
LAST_NAME      FIRST_NAME     ADDRESS
-------------- -------------- --------------------
Ahd            Uiea           55 xxxx ue
```

I need open source software that can do this work. What should i use?

Comment: Do you need this masking only for some Oracle accounts? Should DBA accounts be able to see the original data? If not, how do you plan to recover the original data if necessary?

Comment: i need take data from production database to test databse. but i don't take original data. for this reason i must mask record of tables. i don't need recover to original data. @FrankSchmitt

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORA_HASH or DBMS_CRYPTO package to full fill your requirements. Giving solution using DBMS_CRYPTO:

--Source data:

```
create table customer(last_name varchar2(50),first_name varchar2(50), address varchar2(200));
```

--Encrypt Function(Script [Source](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbms_crypto.htm)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION encrypt_value (p_in IN varchar2, p_key IN raw) RETURN raw IS l_enc_val raw (2000);

 l_mod number := dbms_crypto.ENCRYPT_AES128 + dbms_crypto.CHAIN_CBC + dbms_crypto.PAD_PKCS5;

 BEGIN l_enc_val := dbms_crypto.encrypt ( UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW (p_in, 'AL32UTF8'), l_mod, p_key );

 RETURN l_enc_val;

 END;
```

--Function Implementation:

```
select encrypt_value(last_name,'AABBCC'),encrypt_value(first_name,'AABBCC'), encrypt_value(address,'AABBCC') from customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Enterprise version of Oracle, you can use a [Virtual Private Database (VPD)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#DBSEG007) for this.

A VPD allows you to fine-grained access control (based on the account used to connect to the database). It can:

- return only a subset of rows
- use column masking to display sensitive columns as NULL values

It achieves this by appending a custom *WHERE* clause to *every* query run against the table. There's no way to circumvent it, and no need to adapt existing applications (for using a custom-built view etc.)

To create a VPD for your `customer` table, you need to:

- create a function for generating the *WHERE* clause
- create a policy for your database table
- enable the policy

**Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hide_address (
 v_schema IN VARCHAR2, 
 v_objname IN VARCHAR2)

RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
 result VARCHAR2 (200);

BEGIN
 result := '1=0'; -- evaluates to FALSE for every account
 RETURN (result);
END hide_address;
```

**Creating a policy**

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY(
   object_schema         => 'scott', 
   object_name           => 'customer',
   policy_name           => 'hide_address_policy', 
   policy_function       => 'hide_address',
   sec_relevant_cols     =>' address',
   sec_relevant_cols_opt => dbms_rls.ALL_ROWS);
END;
```

After enabling the policy, *every* query trying to access *CUSTOMER.ADDRESS* will return **NULL**. Depending on your requirements, you might want to add a view to access the table that returns a random address instead of *NULL*:

```
select name, 
  (case when address is NULL 
   then dbms_random.string('', 15) 
   else address end) as address
from 
  customer
```